# cakephp web services how to write an action that allows me to upload a file

Tags: json, web-services, cakephp, rest, file-upload

I am using cakephp 2.1.0

I have a Post Controller that basically creates a Post that has id as integer, title, image as string

I have a controller action that can work with a view that allows me to upload a file and create a new Post record. The action is called admin_add

This is working.

However, I want to expose this action admin_add such that a desktop app built in Adobe Flex can call it.

Preferably I want to use RESTful actions.

Basically I want to create this action as a web service.

Most tutorials I see online tend to be for READ-only actions such as view and index.

What changes do I need to add to the cakephp application code?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have installed this plugin https://github.com/josegonzalez/webservice_plugin and I have this working action but only for html view. https://github.com/josegonzalez/webservice_plugin/issues/7#issuecomment-6149976

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out after sometime.

Assuming the following setup

- Cakephp 2.x
- the action here is public for anonymous users

**Step 1. Install [Webservice Plugin](https://github.com/josegonzalez/webservice_plugin) by josegonzalez.**

Step  1.1. Setup Router::parseExtensions for json

Step  1.2. Add 'Webservice.Webservice' to the components of PostController

Step  1.3. Load the Plugin

---

**Step 2. You need to change the following action for PostController**

```
    public function add() { 
    
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        // create new Post -- this will grab the file from the request data
        $newPost = $this->Post->createNew($this->request->data);
    
        if ($newPost) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Post has been saved'));
            // for normal webpage submission
            if (empty($this->request->params['ext'])) {
                $this->redirect('/');                   
            } else {        
                // for json response to Flex client 
                $result = $newPost;
                $error = null;
                $id = null;
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Post could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            // for json response for failure to create
            if (!empty($this->request->params['ext'])) {
            
                    
                    $result = null;
                    $error = 'Your Post could not be saved.';
                    $id = null;
            
            }
            
        }
        // this is for json response via Webservice.Webservice
        $this->set(compact('result', 'error', 'id'));
        
    }

    }
```

---

**Step 3. Setup your Flex code as stated in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772830/80353). This is [how you then retrieve the JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914689/80353) in Flex Actionscript.**

---

**Step 4. You should expect to get back a json response consisting of the 3 variables result, error, and id and the cake validationErrors. You may choose to blacklist validationErrors as stated in the plugin.**

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your Cakephp app is more or less set up appropriately, but that comes later.  Your challenge now is to get your Adobe Flex code to POST the required data to the Cakephp action url.  I see you're using an admin action so I'm assuming a user login is required to access that action.  I know MINISCULE flex code, but What you'll need to do in Flex is something like this:

1. Have Flex POST to your /user/login page using the username/pw combo that has admin access and save the response cookies and session info into a variable.  Using something like this:

   ```
   var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
   request.method = "POST";
   request.data = variables; //variables includes username and pw
   try {           
       navigateToURL(request);
   }

   catch (e:Error) {
   // handle error here
   }
   ```
2. Then have Flex POST (include cookies in request header) to your admin/posts/action with the image data as the body (content) of the request.

All you then have to do in the cakephp action is to take $this->data['body'] and save it into a file.

Answer (score 1):

On your website you could make a normal form that uploads text and images etc.

Then where ever you want to upload an image from, you would just send the correct POST information.

For example if you wanted to use your service from another server altogether you could use CURL and send the form data using code like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@/folder/image.jpg'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://website.com/posts/add');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm not sure if Flex supports CURL but it should have something similar.